# What does the wording of this question mean?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

I am lost on the wording of this GRE question. What is "total of the ratings given" supposed to be?

[image]

Comment: It's $100 \times (7.8+7.5+4.9-6.5-6.9-4.1)$

Comment: @MathLover So it's saying, the total of the ratings are the score average multiplied by the number of travel agents? Ok I see thanks

Comment: 270, so 250 is the closest approximation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total of the ratings given to all three airlines for reliability is the sum of all the reliability ratings (summing over all the airlines and all the raters).

For example, if there were $2$ raters instead of $100$, and their ratings for reliability were as follows:

Rater #1

- A - $5$
- B - $6$
- C - $8$

Rater #2

- A - $3$
- B - $1$
- C - $4$

Then the total for reliablity would be $5+6+8+3+1+4$